# Active record has_many association for one model having two types of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i am facing a new situation. I know someone definitely had faced these type of situation:

I have an invoices table and an invoice_line_items table. Till now every thing is going well with has_many and belongs to association. Now i want to add tax accounts in invoice items, for that i don't want to create a separate table, hence i make below changes in my invoice model :

invoice.rb:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :invoice_line_items
  has_many :tax_line_items, :class_name => "InvoiceLineItem", :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_line_items, :reject_if => lambda  {|a|a[:account_id].blank? } , :allow_destroy => true

    #validations
         validates_presence_of :invoice_line_items
    validates_associated :invoice_line_items 
end
```

invoice_line_item.rb:

```
class InvoiceLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  end
```

and in my controller i did:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
def new

    @invoice = Invoice.new

        @invoice.invoice_line_items.build
    @invoice.tax_line_items.create 

        @from_accounts = TransactionType.fetch_from_accounts(current_company.id,'sales')
        @to_accounts = TransactionType.fetch_to_accounts(current_company.id, 'sales') 
    @tax_accounts = TransactionType.fetch_from_accounts(current_company.id, 'tax')

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @invoice }
    end
  end
end
```

in my form i did:
for tax accounts

```
 <% @invoice.invoice_line_items.each_with_index do |invoice_line_item, tax_index| %>
                          <%= render "tax_line_items", :invoice_line_item => invoice_line_item, :index => tax_index %>     
                    <% end %>
```

and for invoice items:

```
<% @invoice.invoice_line_items.each_with_index do |invoice_line_item, index| %>
                   <%= render "invoice_line_items", :invoice_line_item => invoice_line_item, :index => index %>
                <% end %>
```

and here are my  partials:
 1)_invoice_line_items.html.erb:

```
<tr id="row<%= index %>" valign="top" >
            <%= hidden_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][id]",invoice_line_item.id%>
            <td valign="top">
                <%= select_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][account_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@from_accounts, :id, :name,:selected => invoice_line_item.account_id ), :include_blank => true, :class=>"full"  %>
              <!-- <a href="/accounts/new?account_head_id=10" > New item</a> -->
            </td>
      <td><%= text_area_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][description]",invoice_line_item.description, :class => "full",:rows =>2 %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][quantity]",invoice_line_item.quantity, :class => 'amount', :id => 'quantity', :onkeydown => "return numbersOnly(event);", :size => 8, :maxlength => 25 %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][unit_rate]",invoice_line_item.unit_rate, :class => 'amount', :id => 'unit_cost', :onkeydown => "return numbersOnly(event);", :size => 8, :maxlength => 20 %></td><!--Jquery code is in application.js-->
      <td><%= text_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][discount_percent]", invoice_line_item.discount_percent, :class => 'amount', :id => 'discount', :onkeydown => "return numbersOnly(event);", :maxlength => 5, :size => 8%></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][amount]", invoice_line_item.amount, :class => 'full', :id => 'total', :readonly => 'readonly',  :size => 5%></td>

            <td><%= link_to 'Remove',{:action => :remove_line_item, :index => index}, :remote => true unless index == 0 %></td>
    </tr>
```

2) _tax_line_items.html.erb:

```
<tr id="tax_row<%= tax_index %>" valign="top" >
   <%= hidden_field_tag "invoice[tax_line_items_attributes][#{tax_index}][id]",invoice_line_item.id%>
   <td></td>
   <td colspan="2" class="ta-right"><label>Add Tax:</label></td>
   <td class="ta-right"  colspan="2" style="background:#EDF4FF">
      <%= select_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{tax_index}][account_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@tax_accounts, :id, :name,:selected => invoice_line_item.account_id ), :include_blank => true, :class=>"full"  %>
      <!-- <a href="/accounts/new?account_head_id=10" > New item</a> -->
   </td>
   <td style="background:#EDF4FF"><%= text_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{tax_index}][amount]", invoice_line_item.amount, :class => 'full', :id => 'tax', :onkeydown => "return numbersOnly(event);", :size => 5%></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Remove',{:action => :remove_tax_item, :index => tax_index}, :remote => true %></td>
</tr>
```

My motto is to save both items accounts and tax accounts in invoice_line_items table's account_id column, i hope some buddy has the answer, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is `@invoice.invoice_line_items` and `@invoice.tax_line_items` will return the same values since they both are using the same id to join.

Seems like you could use [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) (you will have to scroll down to find the section in the API). Using a type column in the `invoice_line_items` table, you can have model inheritance.

```
class InvoiceLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end

class TaxLineItem < InvoiceLineItem
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

then you can cleanup you associations in *Invoice*

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_line_items
  has_many :tax_line_items, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Comment: Thanks @mguymon, but here i have to use only one table invoice_line_items

Comment: Thank you @mguymon i got the solution and below are my answer, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution any how i did this:

```
<% @invoice.tax_line_items.each_with_index do |tax_line_item, tax_index| %>
                          <%= render "tax_line_items", :tax_line_item => tax_line_item, :index => tax_index %>     
                    <% end %>
```

and in the partial of _tax_line_items :

```
<tr id="tax_row<%= tax_index %>" valign="top" >
   <%= hidden_field_tag "invoice[tax_line_items_attributes][#{tax_index}][id]",invoice_line_item.id%>
   <td></td>
   <td colspan="2" class="ta-right"><label>Add Tax:</label></td>
   <td class="ta-right"  colspan="2" style="background:#EDF4FF">
      <%= select_tag "invoice[tax_line_items_attributes][#{tax_index}][account_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@tax_accounts, :id, :name,:selected => invoice_line_item.account_id ), :include_blank => true, :class=>"full"  %>

   </td>
   <td style="background:#EDF4FF"><%= text_field_tag "invoice[tax_line_items_attributes][#{tax_index}][amount]", tax_line_item.amount, :class => 'full', :id => 'tax', :onkeydown => "return numbersOnly(event);", :size => 5%></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Remove',{:action => :remove_tax_item, :index => tax_index}, :remote => true %></td>
</tr>
```

and this is working for me....