# How do edit a line item associated with has_many relationship but uses a single class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an invoice controller and two model invoice and invoice_line_items and create a tax_line_items using invoice_line_item class. Below is my code :

Here is my controller code :

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @menu = 'Income'
    @page_name = 'Create new invoice'
    @invoice = Invoice.new
    @invoice.invoice_line_items.build
    @invoice.tax_line_items.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml { render :xml => @invoice }
    end
  end
end
```

My model for invoice:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :invoice_line_items
  has_many :tax_line_items, :class_name => "InvoiceLineItem",:dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_line_items, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:account_id].blank? } , :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tax_line_items, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:account_id].blank? } , :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and in my forms i used :

```
<%= form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/form_error', :object => @invoice %>
<% @invoice.invoice_line_items.each_with_index do |invoice_line_item, index| %>
                   <%= render "invoice_line_items", :invoice_line_item => invoice_line_item, :index => index %>
                <% end %>
<% @invoice.tax_line_items.each_with_index do |tax_line_item, tax_index| %>
                      <%= render "tax_line_items", :tax_line_item => tax_line_item, :tax_index => tax_index %>     
                <% end %>
<%end%>
```

partials :

1) invoice_line_items:

```
<tr id="row<%= index %>" valign="top" >
            <%= hidden_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][id]",invoice_line_item.id%>
            <td valign="top">
                <%= select_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][account_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@from_accounts, :id, :name,:selected => invoice_line_item.account_id ), :include_blank => true, :class=>"full"  %>
              <!-- <a href="/accounts/new?account_head_id=10" > New item</a> -->
            </td>
      <td><%= text_area_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][description]",invoice_line_item.description, :class => "full", :cols => 10, :rows=>1 %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][quantity]",invoice_line_item.quantity, :class => 'full', :id => 'quantity', :onkeydown => "return numbersOnly(event);", :size => 5, :maxlength => 25 %></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][unit_rate]",invoice_line_item.unit_rate, :class => 'full', :id => 'unit_cost', :onkeydown => "return numbersOnly(event);", :size => 5, :maxlength => 20 %></td><!--Jquery code is in application.js-->
      <td><%= text_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][discount_percent]", invoice_line_item.discount_percent, :class => 'full', :id => 'discount', :onkeydown => "return numbersOnly(event);", :maxlength => 5, :size => 5%></td>
      <td><%= text_field_tag "invoice[invoice_line_items_attributes][#{index}][amount]", invoice_line_item.amount, :class => 'full', :id => 'total', :readonly => 'readonly',  :size => 5%></td>
            <td><%= link_to image_tag("/images/black_icon/ic_cancel.png"),{:action => :remove_line_item, :index => index}, :remote => true unless index == 0 %></td>
    </tr>
```

and 2) tax_line_items:

```
<tr id="tax_row<%= tax_index %>" valign="top" >
   <%= hidden_field_tag "invoice[tax_line_items_attributes][#{tax_index}][id]",tax_line_item.id%>
   <%= hidden_field_tag "invoice[tax_line_items_attributes][#{tax_index}][tax]", tax_line_item.tax, :value => 1 %>
   <td style="background:#EDF4FF"></td>
   <td  class="ta-right" style="background:#EDF4FF" colspan="2"><label>Add Tax:</label></td>
   <td class="ta-right"  colspan="2" style="background:#EDF4FF">
      <%= select_tag "invoice[tax_line_items_attributes][#{tax_index}][account_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@tax_accounts, :id, :name,:selected => tax_line_item.account_id ), :include_blank => true, :class=>"full"  %>
      <!-- <a href="/accounts/new?account_head_id=10" > New item</a> -->
   </td>
   <td style="background:#EDF4FF"><%= text_field_tag "invoice[tax_line_items_attributes][#{tax_index}][amount]", tax_line_item.amount, :class => 'full', :id => 'tax', :onkeydown => "return numbersOnly(event);", :size => 5%></td>
   <td style="background:#EDF4FF"><%= link_to image_tag("/images/black_icon/ic_cancel.png"),{:action => :remove_tax_item, :tax_index => tax_index}, :remote => true %></td>

</tr>
```

I can add new line item entry easily and edit it when their is no tax item. The problem is 
when their is an tax item created in any entry and later try to edit this entry then my line items row appears multiple time for example suppose i have a tax item them a new row will appear for invoice line item ans an extra row for tax line items. i think this will happen because i have used a common table for both the line items. I did this because i have to save both line items entry in same table as both accounts came from same table.
 I am very thankful if anyone have the right answer.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9907784/359120) suggests, you need to add a 'type' column to this table to distinguish between invoice and tax items. It will remove a lot of complications from your code as Rails will do the work of identifying which record belongs to which model class from the common table.

Comment: Thanks @salil i have already try this but as you told about type column i should try this one. Once again thank you for help

Comment: Hi @Salil i tried this but i do not get succeed. Did you mean adding type column in invoice table or line item table

Comment: @ravindra, the answer to your previous question on SO I linked explains how to do it. As it says - by adding type column in the invoice_line_items table, you can have model inheritance and at the same time use the same table. This is single-table inheritance.

Comment: @ravindra, you will need to write your migration so that it adds the appropriate type to the existing records. So, your invoice_line_items table records which are invoices should have type - invoice_line_item and the tax records should have type - tax_line_item. After the migration, any new records created will automatically have correct type.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, i was confused about this but now every thing is clear, i will try this now.